# using cURL to download all files in certain folder, except 404 error page?

Tags: linux, download, curl

I'm using cURL in ubuntu to download some files like

> pic001.jpg
>
> pic002.jpg
>
> pic003.jpg
>
> ...
>
> pic999.jpg

While some files may be missing from this sequence but when I just use

```
 curl -O http://foo.bar/pic[001-999].jpg
```

cURL will download a 404 error page for those missing ones.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

The option `-f` prevents curl from generating any output in case of an server error. See the man page.